# Combination of ember.js and Jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, ember.js

I am trying to build a Jqgrid component using ember.js. Is there any existing solution for this, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Could you include the relevant part of your code?

Comment: If you're looking for something really basic, also see https://github.com/emberjs/list-view

Answer (score 0):

As for jQuery plugins probably the easiest solution is to manually manage a view's content by using the view's `didInsertElement` hook: http://jsbin.com/opobeg/1/edit

The general idea is to access the view's element with `this.$()`, which returns a jQuery object.   Don't forget to tear down event listeners etc. you attached here in the `willDestroyElement` hook!

[Yehuda's article](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/06/11/using-sproutcore-2-0-with-jquery-ui/) describes this mechanism quite well. Although the article very outdated (still referring to SproutCore 2.0), the basic idea haven't changed much since then.

Answer (score 0):

We have done many cool stuff with https://github.com/Addepar/ember-table as base.

Comment: Many other grid systems may cause problem with DOM node's for Ember so it doesent work like expected so extending Addepar's tables with sorting, filtering and pagination was quite easy and works great.